# Docker on Ubuntu Server (Rasberry Pi) failed to create endpoint on network bridge, operation not supported

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker, docker-networking

I am using Ubuntu 21.10 on a Rasberry Pi 4 (aarch64) and when I try to run a Docker (using version 20.10.7) container it returns the following error message:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint goofy_hypatia on network bridge: failed to add the host (veth3da4a58) <=> sandbox (veth987ce17) pair interfaces: operation not supported.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

I have tried the following:

- Rebooting (as suggested by https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/42229)
- Unplugging ethernet and switching to wlan0
- reinstalling docker

Thanks for any help.

Answer:

I had same issue, and after quick search I find solution here: [[Bug 1947601] Cannot start docker container on ubuntu 21.10 server for 64-bit raspberry pi](https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5968593.html)

You need to install [Raspberry Pi Linux kernel extra modules](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/linux-modules-extra-raspi):

`sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-raspi`

Comment: this fixed my problem (ubuntu 21.10, rpi 4 / 8gb / grafana v5.4.3)